# Reload without losing filters / asp-javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a page in which I  can apply different filters. On load the page loads all the entries in the database. After  applying a filter I get the entries of said filter. There is a delete button that performs:

```
Function deleteEntry(code){
  self.location.href="delete.asp?code=" + code;
}
```

After that the original page reloads but loses the filters I had chosen before. How can I make it so I keep the filters after the pressing the delete button (the filters come from different selects/options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call that delete.asp by Ajax. so the original page is not reloaded.

example (with jquery):

```
Function deleteEntry(code){
    $.post("delete.asp", {
        "code": code
    }, function(data) {
        //todo:
        //remove the deleted data from the page per JavaScript...
    }

}
```